# Arma 3 - addAction with dynamic variables to specific Object

Tags: sqf

Playing around with custom composition spawning in Arma 3. I am currently using "LARs Composition Spawn Script" (https://forums.bistudio.com/forums/topic/191902-eden-composition-spawning/) to spawn a custom compostion. Spawning compositions around the map works like a charm.

In the composition there is one object (AI) whith varname "quest_giver". To this specific Object I want to add an Action. My current code is:

```
    // SPAWN RANDOM COMPOSITION ON RANDOM POSITION
    _spawned_composition = [ _random_composition, _pos, [0,0,0], random 360 ] call LARS_fnc_spawnComp;

    // GET OBJECTS FROM THE SPAWNED COMP BACK (ARRAY)
    _objects = [_spawned_composition] call LARs_fnc_getCompObjects;

    // TRYING TO ITERATE THROUGH OBJECTS TO FIND "quest_giver" 
    // AND ADD ACTION TO IT. 
    {
        _type = typeName _x;
        if (_type == "GROUP") then {
            _units = units _x;
            {
                _var = missionNamespace getVariable ["name", _x];
                _name = typeOf _var;
                if (_name == "quest_giver") then {
                    player globalChat format["%1",_name];
                    //_speak = _x addAction ["Speak", {hint format ["Hello, it works !"]}];
                };
            } forEach _units;
        };
    } forEach _objects;
```

Error at `If(_name == "quest_giver")` where _name is an OBJECT but "quest_giver" of course a STRING. So I get `Error Generic error in expression`.

However, _var = missionNamespace getVariable ["name",_x]; returns "quest_giver". But it as an OBJECT, since typeOf _var returns "OBJECT" not STRING.

I just can't figure out the most simpliest thing here I guess. Any idea, if this would even work in theory ?

---

**What I am trying to achieve**

- Create various custom compositions, where on Object in it is always the "quest_giver". Works so far.
- Choose random comp and spawn it on random position in the world. Works so far.
- Add action to the quest giver so player can speak to him. Text Pop up with simple text, content would be a random quest ala bring me 5 x Water Bottles.

I know my way around before and after the add action part but can't figure out how to add action to this specific object. ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unless I'm mistaken, you seem to be confused about how to get the unit's name?
it might be you want to get a name var from the  unit's namespace (if the thing you're using does put it there):

```
_name = _x getVariable ["name" /*var name*/, "" /*default value*/]; 
if (_name == "quest_giver") then { 
//...
```

or more likely (if it's about the name set via editor) with the name function:

```
if ((name _x) == "quest_giver") then {
```

Comment: Thanks @Fusselwurm for your input. Looking at your code I might just had my conditional comparison within the if statement wrong. (I even tried to compare a string with an object, which what I think gave me the error message). I ended up pushing all "quest_giver" objects that I just spawnd into an array (with https://github.com/Wolfenswan/ws_fnc/blob/master/Tools/fn_collectObjects.sqf) and then iterate through the array and addAction to it. Does the job great so far.

Comment: After spawning mutiple different copositions with multiple objects, but each of those had 1 specific object in them ("quest_giver") -> then I think I was more confused about how to get a reference to the "quest_giver" object so I can use addAction on it.

Comment: happy to help, even if it was just a nudge to re-think the issue